# ionic2-calendar/calendar time difference

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

I'm developing an Ionic app and integrationg ionic2-calendar/calendar. I have a problem with iOs. I retrieve data from our SQL database:

start time: 2018-10-30 09:30:00.000 | end time: 2018-10-30 10:30:00.000.

On Android devices and while running the application with ionic serve the start and end time is displayed correctly in the calendar. On iOs devices on the other hand the start time is displayed as 11:30 and the end time as 12:30. I get a 2 hour difference in time.

Has anyone encountered this issue as well?

Comment: Can you please put your live code using https://stackblitz.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this

```
startTime: new Date('2019-09-19T10:30.000Z')
```

This format is not supported in Safari. You'll have to replace '-' with '/', remove the T and everything after the dot (.000Z)

```
startTime: new Date(('2019-09-19T10:30.000Z').replace(/-/g, '/').replace('T', ' ').replace(/\..*|\+.*/, ''))
```